# Django redirects app with development site

Tags: django, redirect, django-settings, django-1.5, django-sites

I have a Django application that exists with complete functionality in both a development and production environment. This is handled by just changing `ALLOWED_HOSTS` appropriately (assuming you don't want to `DEBUG`) and setting up Apache to serve each location properly. My issue is that I want to use the [Django redirects app](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/redirects/) to handle my redirects moving forward (a part of this project is a transition away from PHP) because it means I don't need to deal with these redirects in Apache anymore. Redirects are a larger headache and Apache causes issues with its index.php redirect loops. Also this will allow me to transition more website control under Django, which is a goal for management ease. The problem I am encountering is the redirects app uses the [SITE_ID](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-SITE_ID) to determine a valid target/redirect. The production server has a different hostname than development so I can not test or verify the redirects app. This obviously hurts the purpose of the isolated nearly-identical development server, which is to test all functionality before going live. I understand from the [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/) that individual sites need individual settings.py files and daemons to co-exists, but that again is not helpful to my scenario since the development site is geographically separate from production. It is not clear to me from the documentation:

1) How to add a site, other than adding/altering `SITE_ID` - where do I choose the associated name?

2) Assuming 1, is that the best way (and is adequate) since I already have a different settings.py file?

3) How did I end up with two sites entries for the same `foo.com` and how does this affect my redirects? I only have a single wsgi and settings.py (on each server) but

```
+----+-------------+-------------+
| id | domain      | name        |
+----+-------------+-------------+
|  1 | example.com | example.com |
|  2 | foo.net     | foo.net     |
|  3 | foo.net     | foo         |
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

in my database? I don't see where these sites are added or configured which is leading to my confusion about how to adjust my sites framework to fit the redirects app. Since I am on Django 1.5.4 the sites framework was enabled by default so I've never even thought about it before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the associated site does not matter since redirects just uses id, so I deleted all duplicate sites leaving just id 1 for the actual domain name, set `SITE_ID = 1` in both production and testing configuration. I do not know where the other sites came from since I only used `SITE_ID` to set up redirects, but it works now.